# Bypass final requirement in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

So i have this code - you press the button and then it drafts a card for a player. Currently i've only added a player name on the screen, random_nr will get the card number later, right now it's not needed.

The problem is i have a list, nimedlist, which consists of player names. I would like to go through the list several times while there are still existing cards but the final statement ruined it but i cannot do the int i = 0 in button aswell, because then every time i press the button, it will gain a value 0 again.

Is there any other way to make "i" value changeable? Loops are not an option.

```
                            final int i = 0;
                        //mis juhtub kui nextButtonile vajutada
                        nextButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                            public void handle(final ActionEvent event) {
                                final int random_nr = (int) (Math.random() * (kaardid.size())); 
                                final Label nimi = new Label();
                                nimi.setText((String) nimedlist.get(i));
                                System.out.println(nimedlist.get(i));
                                nimi.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 30));
                                nimi.setTextFill(Color.ORANGE);
                                alustaPiir.getChildren().add(nimi);
                                i++;
                                if (i == nimedlist.size()-1){
                                    i = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Several options here. One is: remove the current declaration of `final int i = 0;`, and instead, add a declaration of `int i=0;` *before* the `handle...` method (so that `i` is a field of the anonymous EventHandler class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the variable as a **field** (instance variable) in a class scope and give a meaningful name:

```
private int currentIndex = 0;
```

and replace all `i`s with this one in your code.